# Runtime Error 9

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am writing a Macro in VBA. This Macro was working fine until I changed the order around and now I am being shown "runtime error 9". After extensive searching on the internet I am at a loose end, I have checked that the sheet name is the same and that the sheet still exists as well as making sure I am referencing the correct workbook. Can anyone tell me why I am being shown this error?

```
Sub CopyStuff()

Sheets("DR1 -TC-001").Select
Range("C2:P23").Select
 'this is the cell range
 Selection.Copy

 With ActiveWorkbook Sheets.Add
 Range("C2:P23").Select
 Selection.Paste = wkb2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs to error on the **With** statement as the **End With** is missing and some periods.

Try this adaptation of your code.

```
Sub CopyStuff()

 Workbooks("With_data.xlsx").Activate
  'Activate the workbook that contains the data you want to copy    
 Sheets("DR1 -TC-001").Range("C2:P23").Copy
  'Copy a range

 ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
  'Revert to the previous new workbook

 With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add
    .ActiveSheet.Range("C2:P23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
 End With
  'Add a sheet and paste the copied range

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
  'Clear the clipboard

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but i am still getting the error in the same place. I have commened out this section of code and the error is the same on all the other variations of this section. :S The end subs and end withs are further down my code i have just given you a section :D

Comment: Which line causes the error? If it is the 'Sheets' line then the issue is with the sheet name.  It is either the spelling of the sheet name or the workbook containing the sheet is not currently the active workbook.  Try this code just before the line to show the active workbook name   "MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name"

Comment: I wuill try that and i have copyed and pasted the names from the sheet. This error only happened when i moved the lines around in my code.

Comment: I did that and it showed me the name of the new workbook but now i have runtime error 438

Comment: To copy from a workbook it needs to be active.  I have modified the code above.  The active window code is used in case your new workbook is not saved yet, as the will cause the workbooks activate to error.

Comment: Workbooks("With_data.xlsx").Activate .... i am having problems with this line is it just activating the workbook and do i need the name or the address of the workbook in the paramiters? (sorry im being thick now :))