# VBA import email content to excel - runtime error 9

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a form on our website which generates an email that looks like this:

```
        First Name: test
        Last Name: test 
        Address1: test 
        Address2: 
        City: test
        State: CA 
        Zip Code: 90032 
        Email: test@yahoo.com 
        Telephone: 
        Date of Birth: -Month- -Day- -Year- 
        Marital Status: 
        Purchase Month: April 
        Purchase Day: -Day- 
        Purchase Year: 2004 
        Purchase Place: test 
        Purchase Place Other: 
        Product type: test 
        Other Product Type: 
        Product size: test 
        Other Product Size: 
        Product color: test
        Did you buy this for yourself or received as a gift? self 
        Which of the following product types do you own or intend to own? 
        •   Skillets & Grills
        •   Specialty
        •   Stockpots
        •   Cast Iron Ovens & Braisers
        •   Kettles
        •   Bakeware
        •   Kitchen Tools
        •   Wine Tools
        Is this your first product? no 
        What do you like to cook? 
        •   Slow Cooking
        •   Kid Friendly Meals
        •   Quick and Easy
        Would you like to receive email updates and special offers? yes 


        comments:
```

I'm trying to get the email content into excel so that each line is a column heading and the user submitted information will go into the row under the heading.  Sometimes a field may be left blank (Not all fields are required).  I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1ab97d9-8fef-46cc-bbe0-e597370ed1c2/export-content-from-outlook-2010-emails-to-excel-spreadsheet?forum=isvvba) and updated the form fields to match my own form, and the path of the spreadsheet. When I run it, the spreadsheet opens but I get "runtime error 9, subscript out of range message. If I click Debug >Toggle Breakpoint it highlights the first line.

Here is the script I'm using.  Can anyone review and help make this work? I have never used macros or VBA before, so this is all foreign to me.  I have searched online for this error but everything I find is very specific and is not helpful to me.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258986/runtime-error-9), [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/639134-visual-basic-applications-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-range.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996486/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range-shows-up-while-trying-to-fetch-the-e) are a few examples of what I have looked at.

```
        Option Explicit

        Sub CopyToExcel()
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim xlWB As Object
        Dim xlSheet As Object
        Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim vText As Variant
        Dim sText As String
        Dim vItem As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        Dim rCount As Long
        Dim bXStarted As Boolean
        Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\llantz\Desktop\prod-reg.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            bXStarted = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Open the workbook to input the data
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Process each selected record
        For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            sText = olItem.Body
            vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
            'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
           rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            rCount = rCount + 1

            'Check each line of text in the message body
            For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
                If InStr(1, vText(i), "First Name:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Last Name:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address1:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address2:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "City:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "State:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Zip Code:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Telephone:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Date of Birth:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Marital Status:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Month:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Day:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Year:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Place:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Place Other:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))

                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Product type:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Other Product Type:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If


                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Product size:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Other Product Size:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Product color:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Did you buy this for yourself or received as a gift?") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Which of the following product types do you own or intend to own?") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Is this your first Le Creuset product?") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "What do you like to cook?") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Would you like to receive email updates and special offers from Le Creuset?") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If

                If InStr(1, vText(i), "comments:") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If
            Next i
            xlWB.Save
        Next olItem
        xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        If bXStarted Then
            xlApp.Quit
        End If
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWB = Nothing
        Set xlSheet = Nothing
        Set olItem = Nothing
        End Sub
```

Comment: `I don't know where to look to tell you what line is causing the problem.` when you get the error, press the button that says "Debug", and it will highlight the offending line. If I had to guess, this error often means that the macro refers to a worksheet that doesn't exist in the Excel file, etc.  Does your workbook have a sheet named `Sheet1`?

Comment: It highlights the first line! Thanks for telling me about that.  My workbook does have a sheet named Sheet1

Comment: You don't want `Debug>Toggle Breakpoint`. That just sets a stopping point in your code. See this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) for how to find the line that's erroring.

Answer (score 3):

On some of the later items there is no colon in the line, such as this one:

"Did you buy this for yourself or received as a gift?"

So splitting it by a colon  (:, which is character 58) will only create a one-element array:

```
vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
```

In the next line you try to reference the 2nd element of the array (Split arrays are zero-based so `(vItem(1)` is the 2nd element):

```
xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
```

Since there is no 2nd element, you get "Error 9 - subscript out of range."

Comment: +1, yup. Always good to include checks for this, especially when you have any user input. Users love to input weird thingS!

Comment: is there a way I can modify this so it would split by colon OR question mark?

Comment: You're welcome! Um, I mean yes, but I'd probably just modify the lines in question, to `vItem = Split(vText(i), "?")`.